# regex skip match if its follows by whitespace and a keyword

Tags: php, regex, regex-negation

Currently trying to match comments with regexes but only if no function follows.
Currently I use a regex which also matches the keyword function.
And then check in the source code (php) if this group is set or not.

```
/\/\*\*.*?\*\/\s*(function)?/sg
```

https://regex101.com/r/l0j1ip/1

Now the question is whether it is possible to realize with pure regex.
I have tried it with a simple negative lookahead but without success.
Although the comment is no longer made individually, but then just with the subsequent comment.

```
/\/\*\*.*?\*\/\s*(?!function)/sg
```

https://regex101.com/r/PuUUw6/1

Next I tried non capture group. But also there without success.

```
/(?:\/\*\*.*?\*\/\s*function)|\/\*\*.*?\*\/\s*/sg
```

https://regex101.com/r/wkQE7E/1

After a comment with the information (*SKIP)(*FAIL) I also tried it without success.
All matches above this keyword are skipped. Also the single matches are skipped.

```
/\/\*\*.*?\*\/\s*function(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|\/\*\*.*?\*\//sg
```

https://regex101.com/r/OJSFrF/1

Comment: have you tried using backtracking control verbs `(*SKIP)(*FAIL)` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After reading the question again, it should be doable using negative lookahead ; the repetition must be inside the negative expression:

```
/\/\*\*((?!\*\/).)*\*\/(?!\s*function)/sg
```

Seems you need to understand better how backtracking works, using `.*?` instead of `.*` means the regex engine will try first to match everything after before `.*` however the negative lookahead makes the match fail and `.*` continues to match. Using `((?!\*\/).)*` can't match `\*\/` wheras `.*?` can, after backtracking.
Another solution is to use atomic group `(?>\/\*\*.*?\*\/)(?!\s*function)`.

Comment: Just as an extra info: atomic groups are more performant. It requires less steps.

Thank you. I am also very grateful to you that you have also directly packed an explanation with it.

Answer (score 2):

Another option without the `/s` flag could be

```
/\*\*(?:[^*]*+|\*(?!/)[^*]*+)*\*/(?!\s*function)
```

The pattern matches:

- `/\*\*` Match `/**`
- `(?:` Non capture group

  - `[^*]*+` Match any char except `*` using a possessive quantifier
  - `|` Or
  - `\*(?!/)` Match `*` not followed by `/`
  - `[^*]*+` Match any char except `*` using a possessive quantifier
- `)*` Close non capture group and optionally repeat
- `\*/` Match `*/`
- `(?!\s*function)` Negative lookahead, assert not optional whitspace chars followed by function to the right

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Ykdt49/1)

Note that you don't have to escape the backslash when using a different delimiter.

```
$regex = '~/\*\*(?:[^*]*+|\*(?!/)[^*]*+)*\*/(?!\s*function)~';
```

Comment: Oooh, 100k points , congrats 4th Bird. 